# How can I use FadeOutThemeAnimation in codebehind?

Tags: c#, uwp

Here is XAML:

```
<Frame x:Name="Chapter"></Frame>
```

And here is codebehind:

```
Storyboard ChangeChapterSB = new Storyboard();
FadeOutThemeAnimation FOTA = new FadeOutThemeAnimation();
FOTA.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);            
FOTA.TargetName = Chapter.Name;
ChangeChapterSB.Children.Add(FOTA);
ChangeChapterSB.Begin();
```

Whereas, the Visual Studio throw a new exception that:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:Cannot resolve TargetName
>   Chapter.

I have set the `x:Name` yet, why did it throw this exception? And how can I use `FadeOutThemeAnimation` in codebehind?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to note here.

First, `FadeOutThemeAnimation` is pre-configured animation that won't allow you to configure the `Duration` of the animation. I saw you set it to `2s` and that just won't do anything.

Second, you will need to use `Storyboard.SetTarget()` instead of `TargetName`, so the following code should work.

```
Storyboard ChangeChapterSB = new Storyboard();
FadeOutThemeAnimation FOTA = new FadeOutThemeAnimation();
ChangeChapterSB.Children.Add(FOTA);
Storyboard.SetTarget(FOTA, Chapter);
ChangeChapterSB.Begin();
```

---

Alternatively, check out this [`Animate`](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/0015a96897c138e09d8604267df46da936b66838/Continuity/Extensions/AnimationExtensions.cs#L73) helper method which allows you to fully control a `DoubleAnimation`.

In your case, you just just write

```
Chapter.Animate(null, 0, nameof(Opacity), 2000);
```

A lot simpler, right?

Comment: Oh,I think if I use DoubleAnimation is more useful than FadeOutThemeAnimation beaucase of the Duration.